# openCV throws an error when trying to run the code, it tells me that the function (cvNameWindow) is not implemented

Tags: c++, opencv

Full error message

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  OpenCV(4.9.0-dev) /home/princess-ellie/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1255: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'.

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(img_processing VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(img_processing main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( img_processing ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int, char **) {
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("lena.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::namedWindow("Lena", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Lena", image);
    return 0;
}
```

*c_cpp_properties.json*

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/princess-ellie/opencv/include",
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4",
                "/usr/local/lib",
                "/usr/local/bin"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++23"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

A weird part about it, it worked on my other project before I changed the name of the folder and project, then I decided to delete it and start with a new project but now the issue still persists.

I'm *assuming* it is something with `vscode` configurations but have no idea and would like this issue solved.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally buillt a *"headless"* version. Try printing `cv2.getBuildInformation()` or whatever it is called to see the options it was built with.

Comment: @Mark I'm currently trying to reinstall opencv, I found an opencv4 folder under /usr/local/include/opencv4 and there is a file called highgui.hpp and no cpp file of it, i'm not sure  what that is because I only used git clone on their github so maybe somewhere it created the folder? I honestly have no idea but it is seems to be a problem with highgui, vscode tells me that the functions are not implement and I looked into that hpp file and there are declarations of those functions.
EDIT: the git did install the opencv4 at the end

Comment: Try running `cv.getBuildInformation()` like I suggested before and click [edit] and add the output to your question.

Comment: @MarkSetchell hi sorry for the delayed response I kinda forgot about this post , I did solve this problem by reinstalling openCV, I'm not sure how to mark this as closed, and I can't mark you're comment as answer, I'll try to close it when I find the button to do so. if you are curious I can run `cv.getBuildInformation()' and post it although it does work now so I don't know what will that provide, anyway thanks and let me know.